# How to count the number of storage accounts having specific tag in Azure Policy?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I want to create an `Azure Policy` for storage accounts. During the creation of a storage account, it will count the number of storage accounts in the subscription which has a specific tag (like env:dev). If the number of this count exceeds 10, It should **deny** the creation of that storage account.

How I can **count** the number of **storage account which has certain tag** inside an **Azure Policy** declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not something you can do using Azure Policy.

Even though the approach seems valid, the `count` operator is meant to be used with `[*] aliases` - see [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-count-operator). One could think of scanning `Microsoft.Subscription` aliases, but running the command `az provider show --namespace Microsoft.Subscription --expand "resourceTypes/aliases" --query "resourceTypes[].aliases[].name"`, what you get as an output is so far not extensive :

```
[
  "Microsoft.Subscription/SubscriptionDefinitions/subscriptionId",
  "Microsoft.Subscription/SubscriptionDefinitions/subscriptionDisplayName",
  "Microsoft.Subscription/SubscriptionDefinitions/offerType",
  "Microsoft.Subscription/SubscriptionDefinitions/etag",
  "Microsoft.Subscription/aliases/subscriptionId"
]
```

Also, the way the policy engine works wouldn't allow you to count the number of instances meeting a particular rule : each ARM component is scanned individually and compared to the rules defined in the policy. You cannot see "all Storage Accounts in a given scope" - each one is scanned without the whole picture being seen at any point. That is why I started with looking if the Subscription object had something like a `Resources [*]` alias.